# transition matrix for Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Can any one help me to solve this home work please?

> The city of Sacramento recently completed a new light rail system to bring commuters and shoppers into the downtown area and relieve freeway congestion.City planner estimate that each year, 15% of those who drive or ride in an automobile will change to the light rail system; 80% will continue to use automobile; and the rest will no longer go to the downtown area. Of those who use light rail, 5% will go back to using an automobile, 80% will continue to use light rail, and the rest will stay out of the downtown area. Assume those who do not go downtown will continue to stay out od the down town area.
>
> a. Write a transition matrix
>
> b. Find the probability that a person who commuted by automobile ends up avoiding the downtown area

thanks a lot

---

Edit 1)

For transition matrix I wrote this:

[image]

Is this true?

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem. Did you try anything?

Comment: Take initial state $(100, 0, 0)$, meaning that $100$ people use automobiles and there are no other people, and see how that works out.

Comment: This looks like the exact same question you asked before.

Comment: One of the states is absorbing, the MC has a finite number of states and is aperiodic. What can you deduce from this?

Comment: Please help me. Orginal question: http://www.learningace.com/doc/7738386/ffe0cd00c9a77fdf0a45979740b7242e/chapter-10-markov-chains

Comment: Follow the suggestion I gave you for the previous question. It is exactly the same.

Comment: The table looks good.

Comment: Table is okay. The title of the section is "Absorbing Markov Chain". That should tell you something! I suggest you read the chapter and see what that term means. Hint: It is a chain where one or more states absorb all the transitions and the chain always "ends" there.